# Sending Email with Lotus Notes - (Different Database) - Excel VBA

Tags: database, vba, excel, lotus-notes

I have a tiny problem with a VBA that I prepared to send emails from a database in lotus notes (other than the main database)

When I send the same email from the main database in lotus notes, (username database) I have no problems, it runs smoothly. However, the same coding, I just change the server and the database name, it sends the emails but with a message screen in lotus notes as "do you want to save your changes?" I need to select yes or no, then it sends the emails. As I said, the only difference is the database and the server in the coding.

Here is the message in Lotus Notes:

[image]

Here is the VBA code.

```
Sub SendWithLotus()
Dim NSession As Object
Dim NDatabase As Object
Dim NUIWorkSpace As Object
Dim NDoc As Object
Dim NUIdoc As Object
Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set NUIWorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
Set NDatabase = NSession.GETDATABASE("XXXXX/XXX/XXXServer", "mail\YYYYY")
```

'=> this is the main change, if I want to send from the main mail database, I don't enter anything inside the brackets and everyting works fine.

```
If Not NDatabase.IsOpen Then
    NDatabase.OPENMAIL
End If

'Create a new document

Set NDoc = NDatabase.CREATEDOCUMENT

With NDoc
    .SendTo = Range("O8").Value
    .CopyTo = ""
    .Subject = Range("O7").Value

    'Email body text, including marker text which will be replaced by the Excel cells

    .body = vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "**Cell Contents**" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        ""

    .Save True, False
End With

'Edit the just-created document to copy and paste the Excel cells into it

Set NUIdoc = NUIWorkSpace.EDITDOCUMENT(True, NDoc)

With NUIdoc

    'Find the marker text in the Body item

    .GOTOFIELD ("Body")
    .FINDSTRING "**Cell Contents**"
    '.DESELECTALL            'Uncomment to leave the marker text in place (cells are inserted immediately before)

    'Replace it with the Excel cells

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:L58").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
    .Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .Send
    .Close
    NDoc.SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = True
End With

Set NSession = Nothing
    NDatabase = Nothing
    NDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

The reason might be settings of the different database or I might need to code to close that message box in Lotus Notes, but I don't know how.

Comment: Search for the send keys method of VBA, to send the enter key to dismiss the message.

Comment: I'm looking very hard for that :) no chance as of now. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.contextures.com/excelvbasendkeys.html

Comment: Your comment about the "main change" is ambiguous. Which brackets, on which line of code, are you talking about?  How about just showing both versions, with one commented out?

Comment: You're working with both NDoc and NUIdoc. That's a bit confusing.  You're not showing how you're creating either of them. That means we have to guess what's going on. I see why you're using the NUIdoc, but from that point on you should probably stop working with NDoc, but I see that you're calling NUIDoc.Send and NUIDoc.Close method, and then after you've already done that you're setting NDoc.SaveMessageOnSend. That makes little sense.

Comment: Thank you Richard.
Before;

Set NDatabase = NSession.GETDATABASE("", "")

After;

Set NDatabase = NSession.GETDATABASE("XXXXX/XXX/XXXServer", "mail\YYYYY")

Comment: The first one sends the message. With the change, (sending from another database) it just creates the mail and asks, "do you want to save changes".

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say, but one database may have a different default form than the other, and your code may be using it.  I'd suggest adding a field on the Notes document called SaveOptions and set the value to 0.  Try:

```
NUIDoc.Document.ReplaceItemValue("SaveOptions",0)
```

before sending.

Comment: Thank you but, didn't work. After this edit, it's not asking to save the changes, leaving the mail drafted, ready to be sent.

Comment: "'Edit the just-created document to copy and paste the Excel cells into it" Except NUIWorkSpace.EditDocument is not NDoc.  NDoc is a completely different object.

Comment: You invoke the send method on NUIDoc, but never send NDoc (you just save it,) That's why it's "sitting" there.